# Sources of derived schemes in geometric representation theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory

What are some derived schemes naturally arising in geometric representation theory? 
Some examples include:

- Steinberg scheme
- Hilbert scheme
- Moduli stack of local systems.

Now, this looks like a community wiki question to me so maybe it should be marked as such.

Comment: What do you call a derived scheme?

Comment: either the definition in simplicial context or connective spectral context (and stacks are allowed too)

Comment: Opening "On two geometric realizations of an affine Hecke algebra" by Bezrukavnikov, or most recent papers by Gaitsgory should give a good supply :) I also found Mirkovic-Riche "Linear Koszul duality" rather beautiful ... innocent enough, but the idea is very nice.